# Error while updating the column values based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, group-by, valueerror

The MRE is presented here ,the original data frame df1 has several columns and several rows.
Col C of df1  takes  two values in the data frame 0 0r 1 only.
There is a reference data frame df2 which has few values of  df1(col B) which need to be targeted(all unique)

objective - To update Target column in df1 based on two  conditions.
1)if col B is in df2
2)value of col C should be equal to 0
update Target column of those specific  rows to 'same values of Target columns with cols C as 1 'for same type of col B rows .Leave rows with col C values of 1 untouched.

Run the function for full df1

Code for sample data presented below.

```
A=np.arange(10)
B=['A','A','A','B','B','C','C','C','D','D']
C=[0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1]
Target=[4,3,2,2,3,4,2,1,3,2]

df1=pd.DataFrame({'A':A,'B':B,'C':C,'Target':Target})
df1
A   B   C   Target
0   0   A   0   4
1   1   A   0   3
2   2   A   1   2
3   3   B   1   2
4   4   B   0   3
5   5   C   0   4
6   6   C   1   2
7   7   C   0   1
8   8   D   0   3
9   9   D   1   2

df2=pd.DataFrame({'B2':['A','B','C']})
df2
B2
0   A
1   B
2   C
```

Function as below.

```
def normalise(df):
        for i in df2:
                target=df['Target'][(df['B']==i)&(df['C']==1)]
                revised_target=np.where(df['B']==0,target,df['Target'])
                df['Target']=revised_target

normalise(df1)
```

when run it gives error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-294-70448fdf25ce> in <module>
----> 1 normalise(df1)

<ipython-input-293-d57ba911bf88> in normalise(df)
      2         for i in df2:
      3                 target=df['Target'][(df['B']==i)&(df['C']==1)]
----> 4                 revised_target=np.where(df['B']==0,target,df['Target'])
      5                 df['Target']=revised_target
      6 

<__array_function__ internals> in where(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,) (0,) (10,)
```

Hi can any one help me out for the error in the loop.

It will be helpful even if you can suggest a function to use the only df1 as the df2 is subsetted from df1 only (all of df1 rows with col C as 1)

**Edited version:**
I was waiting for the solution.In the mean time i had tried to run the below and encountered error.

Objective is:
With the data grouped under column['idhogar'] update only the value of column['Target'] same as that of the Target column value for the rows whose column['parentesco1'] value is 0. Leave value of column['parentesco1'] ==1 rows as it is.

Code snippet from original data set as below.
The orginal data set (having 143 columns) with selective columns for the function  is of the structure as below:

```
    df_train[['idhogar','parentesco1','Target']].head()
    
    idhogar parentesco1 Target
    0   21eb7fcc1   1   4
    1   0e5d7a658   1   4
    2   2c7317ea8   1   4
    3   2b58d945f   0   4
    4   2b58d945f   0   4
```

Below is the structure of the grouped data for one value of groupby to understand the structure of data in groupby object.

```
grouped=df_train.groupby('idhogar')
group_row=grouped.get_group('09e25d616')
group_row.iterrows
<bound method DataFrame.iterrows of                 Id  v2a1  hacdor  rooms  hacapo  v14a  refrig  v18q  v18q1  \
7589  ID_7e24baf68   NaN       0      6       0     1       1     0    NaN   
7590  ID_bf56eb3d9   NaN       0      6       0     1       1     0    NaN   
7591  ID_f8f357aae   NaN       0      6       0     1       1     0    NaN   
7592  ID_91adf2513   NaN       0      6       0     1       1     0    NaN   

      r4h1  ...  SQBescolari  SQBage  SQBhogar_total  SQBedjefe  SQBhogar_nin  \
7589     2  ...            0       9              16         49             4   
7590     2  ...           36    1156              16         49             4   
7591     2  ...           49     841              16         49             4   
7592     2  ...            0      49              16         49             4   

      SQBovercrowding  SQBdependency  SQBmeaned  agesq  Target  
7589         1.777778            1.0      42.25      9       2  
7590         1.777778            1.0      42.25   1156       2  
7591         1.777778            1.0      42.25    841       2  
7592         1.777778            1.0      42.25     49       1  

[4 rows x 143 columns]>
```

I was trying to use a function which creates a groupby function on the data set and run the loop inside the groupby object. But facing problem with the error.

df_train['rev_target']=np.nan

Function for applying on entire df

```
def target_transform(df):
    grouped = df.groupby('idhogar')
    for group_index,group_df in grouped:
        target_poverty=group_df['Target'][group_df['parentesco1']==1]
            
        for index,row in group_df.iterrows():
                row['rev_target']=target_poverty
                target_rev_df=pd.DataFrame({'Orig_Target':row['Target'],'Rev_Target':row['rev_target']})
                
                return target_rev_df

df_train_transformed=df_train.apply(target_transform)
```

Error faced is:

```
KeyError: 'idhogar'
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

**Editted (data frame structure with only the required columns furnished below for better clarity)**

```
df_train[['idhogar','parentesco1','Target']][(df_train['idhogar']=='09e25d616')|(df_train['idhogar']=='078a0b6e2')|(df_train['idhogar']=='0511912b6')]

idhogar parentesco1 Target
2311    0511912b6   1   4
2312    0511912b6   0   4
2313    0511912b6   0   4
2314    0511912b6   0   3
7589    09e25d616   0   2
7590    09e25d616   0   2
7591    09e25d616   1   2
7592    09e25d616   0   1
8380    078a0b6e2   1   1
8381    078a0b6e2   0   2
8382    078a0b6e2   0   2
8383    078a0b6e2   0   1
```

Also to be informed that for some rows the column'Target' value is same irrespective of the value in column 'parentesco1' (0 or 1).But the function should have to be run on the entire df.

Comment: Your second paragraph of objective is not immediate clear. Human language tends not to be as precise as numbers. Please show desired results namely *revised_target* with data given df1 and df2.

Comment: @Parfait     Thanks for your response. I shall try to elaborate . Column 'parentesco1' shall take only two values '0' or '1'. Rows with value'1' need to be left status quo.                  For group of rows under a group formed under column''idhogar',Rows which have the column ' parentesco1' as '0' need to be updated with values of column 'Target' with values same as that of values pertaining to the rows with value of '1'. For eg if 'Target ' value is 4 for the row with ' parentesco1' as1.The same value 4 need to be updated for all the rows grouped under one value of ''idhogar' column.

Comment: @Parfait - Iam trying to create and empty field and populate ,using the created function to that column.Later on during modeling i will delete the original 'Target' column. I dont know how to update the source data frame and hence iam creating new data frame with same index along with original target and transformed target. Original data frame updation option if available shall be more comfortable to implement.Thanks.

Comment: @Parfait  - I had added the snapshot of the data frame rows pertaining to three values of ''idhogar" column.Hope this shall provide clarity of df.